# Difference between ES2015 `import * as` vs just plain `import`

Tags: import, module, coffeescript, ecmascript-6

I just fixed a bug by changing `import * as CodeMirror` to just plain `import CodeMirror`.

- I copied [this code](https://github.com/phosphorjs/phosphor-codemirror/blob/7c06a31421a84da1317cdd536f8415d51796487a/src/index.ts#L10). (Porting it from TypeScript)
- `import * as CodeMirror` worked until an addon was imported for its side effects: the expected new `fold` property was undefined.

**Questions:** (I am trying to understand what happened better)

- What is going on? How did this change fix the bug?
- Who is adding the `default` property to CodeMirror? (Or more likely: wrapping the module inside another object that looks very similar) The most likely suspects:

  - JavaScript modules (ES2015)
  - Babel
  - Webpack
  - CoffeeScript
  - CodeMirror
- Is there a better way to accomplish what I was trying to achieve?

---

**More details:**

*This code doesn't work as expected:*

```
import * as CodeMirror from 'codemirror'
import 'codemirror/addon/fold/indent-fold.js'  # should add `fold` object to `CodeMirror`

console.log typeof CodeMirror          ## 'object'
console.log typeof CodeMirror.fold     ## 'undefined'
console.log typeof CodeMirror.default  ## 'function'  

## Work-around:
console.log typeof CodeMirror.default.fold  ## 'object'
```

*This code works as expected:*

```
import CodeMirror from 'codemirror'
import 'codemirror/addon/fold/indent-fold.js'  # should add `fold` object to `CodeMirror`

console.log typeof CodeMirror          ## 'function'
console.log typeof CodeMirror.fold     ## 'object'
console.log typeof CodeMirror.default  ## 'undefined'
```

---

I have already studied these resources, but they have not helped me fully understand what happened:

- [JS import reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import)
- [JS export reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/export)
- [CoffeeScript modules](http://coffeescript.org/#modules)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Let's assume you have a very simple module named 'test-module', in it you have:

```
var test = 'test';
export default test;
export function helloWorld () { ... };
```

When you do:

```
import something from 'test-module';
```

you are only importing the default export of 'some-module'. In this case, it is the string test. The default export can be anything, object, function, etc.

When you do:

```
import {helloWorld} from 'test-module';
```

You are specifically importing a member of 'test-module' named 'helloWorld' and not the default export. In this case, it is the function 'helloWorld'.

If you had done:

```
import {something} from 'test-module';
```

The 'something' would be 'undefined' since there is no export for with that name.

```
import * as something from 'test-module';
```

is asking for an object with all of the named exports of 'test-module'.

Then you can access any of the exports in 'test-module' as something.name. In this case they will be `something.default` and `something.helloWorld`.

Comment: Should probably change `something.default` to `something['default']` (just like with all keyword properties) as not all transpilers will do this for you and it will error on older browsers.

Answer (score 1):

`import * as CodeMirror from 'codemirror'` imports all the *named exports* and namespaces them into an object called `CodeMirror`.

`import CodeMirror from 'codemirror'` imports the *default export*.

Comment: Is it normal for there to be a `CodeMirror.default` property as a result of`import * as CodeMirror from 'codemirror'`? I don't think `codemirror` explicitly named an export called "default"

Comment: They probably have a default export marked as `export default <whatever>`, and I think when you do a wildcard import, that comes in under the key `default`.