# While using moment in Angular 7 getting Error:TypeError: moment is not a function

Tags: angular, momentjs

followed below steps to install and use moment:

```
npm install moment --save
```

In app.component.ts file:

```
import * as moment from 'moment';



export class AppComponent{
    currentDate = moment();
```

Also added below code in angular.json as per [this article](https://medium.com/@jek.bao.choo/steps-to-add-moment-js-to-angular-cli-f9ab28e48bf0):

```
"scripts": ["./node_modules/moment/min/moment.min.js"]
```

I get:

```
TypeError: moment is not a function
```

Please check repro [demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-8lyvre)

If you know why I am getting this error please assist.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

import is fine:

```
import * as moment from 'moment';
```

You also need to install the type definition so that the typescript compiler can resolve the types specific to moment.js:

```
npm install @types/moment
```

Comment: Hi, thanks a lot for looking into this. Can you tell me what is difference between import * as moment from 'moment'; and import  moment from 'moment'; and why we need npm install @types/moment when using import * as moment from 'moment'; statement?

Comment: These two links explain it well: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36795819/when-should-i-use-curly-braces-for-es6-import?rq=1 and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40287795/difference-between-es2015-import-as-vs-just-plain-import.  The '*' version imports all named exports accessed from a common alias "as <something>".  The other version imports the default export (If there is one) - if there isn't one, then its an error.

Comment: I'm on Angular7 and having the same error. Also @type/moment is deprecated. "deprecated @types/moment@2.13.0: This is a stub types definition for Moment (https://github.com/moment/moment). Moment provides its own type definitions, so you don't need @types/moment installed!"

Answer (score 3):

import * as temp from 'moment';
const moment = temp["default"];

Answer (score 2):

```
import moment from "moment";
```

This fixed the problem for me when `import * as moment from 'moment';` wasn't working.

And again from my comment, @type/moment is deprecated.

According to them:

> "Moment provides its own type definitions, so you don't need
>   @types/moment installed!"